# Python: How do I append (add a single character) to the end of the first line of a txt or phylip file

Tags: python, python-3.x, append, biopython

I have a phylip file that looks like this (only showing first 3 lines):

```
           6   39

 Archaeopt   CGATGCTTACCGCCGATGCT

 Hesperorni   CGTTACTCGTTGTCGTTACT
```

But I want to add "I" right behind the integer 39. How can I go about this?
I have tried using append but it adds it to the end of the file which isn't what I want.
Thanks.
I want it to look like this:

```
            6   39I

 Archaeopt   CGATGCTTACCGCCGATGCT

 Hesperorni   CGTTACTCGTTGTCGTTACT
```

Here's is what I did:

```
       aln = open(r"C:\Users\Idowu\Downloads\paml\ref.phy","a")
       aln.write("I")
       aln.close()
```

And this was the outcome:

```
6   39
Archaeopt   CGATGCTTAC CGCCGATGCT
Hesperorni   CGTTACTCGT TGTCGTTACT
Baluchithe   TAATGTTAAT TGTTAATGTT
B. virgini   TAATGTTCGT TGTTAATGTT
Brontosaur   CAAAACCCAT CATCAAAACC
B.subtilis   GGCAGCCAAT CACGGCAGCC

TACCGCCGAT GCTTACCGC
CGTTGTCGTT ACTCGTTGT
AATTGTTAAT GTTAATTGT
CGTTGTTAAT GTTCGTTGT
CATCATCAAA ACCCATCAT
AATCACGGCA GCCAATCACI
```

As you would notice the I was added at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('1.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()


data1 = data[0].split('\n')
data1[0] = data1[0] + 'I'

data[0] = ''.join(data1[0]) + '\n'

with open('1.txt','w') as f:
    for i in data:
        f.write(i)
```

- First two lines of code reads all lines in files and stores each line of file in form of list.
- Next three line of code takes first line of file and **append 'I'** to it.
- And last three lines override the data in file and you get your desired result

Comment: you can try this code and you will get o/p as you wanted

Answer (score 1):

```
# open the file
with open('testDataFile.txt', 'r') as original:
    # get all file content into a variable
    allLines = original.readlines()

# modify first line of the data
allLines[0] = allLines[0].rstrip() + "I\n"

# open the the same file in write mode
modifyFile = open('testDataFile.txt', 'w')

# Iterate all lines and write into the file
for i in allLines:
    modifyFile.write(i)
modifyFile.close()
```

Comment: That should be a letter "I", not a vertical bar. But it's a perfectly good answer; I don't understand why @Rob deleted it.

Comment: Ok, I should add that "good" is putting it too strongly. It certainly *is* an answer, but code-only answers are discouraged: You should explain what this does to get around the problem that the OP encouraged. It seems perfectly obvious, but it isn't obvious to all readers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. If you agree with the code, Can you please upvote my answer. I'm a beginner of SOF, I shall take care of those mistakes. Please check if this works @Idowu

Comment: Welcome to the site. The OP had already accepted an answer before you posted, and as a new user he might not come back to the site until he has another problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SAMIULHUDA your answer worked perfectly for my problem.